Why can't RPA Windows or pywinauto libraries click on a background WPF element without a valid WindowHandle, while UiPath can?
Problem Description:
I am working with Robot Framework using Python to automate a desktop application developed in the WPF framework. My specific requirement is to click on an element in the background (i.e., without bringing the application to the foreground).
However, I’ve encountered the following issue:
When using Robot Framework’s libraries like RPA.Windows or pywinauto, I can only click on the element if the application is in the foreground.
The same operation works seamlessly in UiPath, even with the application in the background.
Additionally:

The target element in the application does not have a valid WindowHandle, as is common with WPF elements.

What I’ve Tried:

Verified that Robot Framework can locate the element using RPA.Windows.Get Attribute or similar methods.
Confirmed that UiPath successfully interacts with the same element in the background.
Studied that both Robot Framework (via pywinauto or RPA.Windows) and UiPath use Microsoft UI Automation Framework for interaction.
Attempted alternative approaches like using pywinauto’s uia_controls, but the issue persists.

Observations:

WPF elements are known for having no native WindowHandle, relying instead on UI Automation tree structures for interaction.
UiPath handles the element interaction effectively in the background, possibly leveraging additional mechanisms beyond standard UI Automation APIs.

Questions:

What extra mechanisms or frameworks does UiPath use to interact with WPF elements in the background that are not present in Robot Framework or pywinauto?
Is there a workaround or additional configuration required in Robot Framework to enable background interactions with WPF elements that lack a valid WindowHandle?

What I’m Looking For:
An understanding of how UiPath achieves background automation in such scenarios.
Suggestions for enabling similar behavior in Robot Framework or pywinauto.
Potential limitations or workarounds when working with WPF elements in Robot Framework.
Environment Details:
Target Application Framework: WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation)
Automation Tool: Robot Framework
Language: Python
Libraries Used: RPA.Windows, pywinauto
Comparison Tool: UiPath
If required, I can provide code snippets, application screenshots, or additional details about the element and attributes retrieved via UI Automation tools. Thank you in advance for your insights and suggestions!
